# change of variable in an ODE equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am having a hard time understand how to get the equation here (the one circled) using change of variable. It says it uses $t=\lambda x$, and then new equation is the one in circle, but I am not sure how. Also in the new equation, the $y''$, is it actually $y''(t)$? so the y in the new equation is a function of t, is it correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, multiply the given DE by $x$.

Take $t = \lambda x$ , then $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{dy}{dx} $$.

Further $$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Now by substituting $\lambda = \frac tx$ we get $xy' = t\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $x^2y'' = t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ and $\lambda^2x^2y = t^2y$